# How to analyze what set of ten numbers is repeated? (LOTTO)

Tags: regex, text, repeat, emeditor

How to analyze what set of ten numbers is repeated?

Each set has 20 different numbers. From `1` to `80`.

How to do it in EmEditor text editor?

*Example:*

> 03,04,05,09,12,15,20,24,26,28,31,33,35,37,43,48,64,70,72,75
>   06,05,07,10,12,15,21,24,30,28,31,39,35,37,43,49,64,70,72,76

CSV File:
https://www25.zippyshare.com/v/0gLFugWf/file.html

Comment: What is the expected output of this analysis?

Comment: From the entire list - from item number 4680 to the current one (I attached a CSV file). Calculate a set of 'ten numbers' that repeat, that is, the number of occurrences of a set of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This uses the Bookmark Duplicates dialog to bookmark all duplicates.

1. Change the User-defined CSV format to use the ";" delimiter. If you don't see the CSV toolbar, go to View | Toolbars | CSV/Sort toolbar. Go to Customize CSV for User-defined format and change Delimiter to ";". Press OK, then click on User-defined separated to go to view the file as a table.

[image]

2. Go to Delete/Bookmark Duplicate Lines (Advanced).

[image]

3. Change the settings like in the screenshot. I'm only looking for duplicates in the lotto numbers. Press the Bookmark button.

[image]

4. At this point, the duplicate entries are bookmarked. The status bar at the bottom shows the number of duplicates. You can navigate the bookmarks with F2 and shift+F2.

Comment: How to use the "Extract" option show all duplicates in sets of numbers, so it would be much faster and simpler.

Comment: I did as you directed me, but I do not see any results - "0 duplicate lines were found"

Comment: Find:                             
03,04,05,09,12,15,20,24,26,28,31,33,35,37,43,48,64,70,72,75 06,05,07,10,12,15,21,24,30,28,31,39,35,37,43,49,64,70,72,76                                                I want Result:05,12,15,24,28,31,35,37,43,64,70,72

Comment: @Nero Okay, I see what you are trying to solve now. EmEditor cannot find matching sets, and I don't know of a program that can do this. I think you will need to write a program to do this.

Comment: A program exists, but doing the action would last for centuries, because it is well over a 1,600,000,000,000+ sets of numbers :(
That's why it's better to do it in a Text Editor